# How to peel shell of boiled eggs without damaging the egg?

Tags: kitchen

How can I peel the shell of boiled eggs without damaging the egg ?

Answer (score 1):

In general, if eggs are too fresh the shell won't separate from the eggwhite without ripping of parts from the egg.

So if you have the right eggs (approx 5 days old from laying) I recommend to break the shell of the egg by hitting it gently onto a hard but even surface like a table. You should to break the shell all around in pieces not bigger than 1 cm in diameter. Then start from the bottom of the egg with peeling it piece by piece.

This should yield the best result.